# Can I implement dynamic iframes using embed code templates?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, next.js

I am creating an nextjs application and want to allow users to view apple music, youtube, and spotify embeds on the client side. I figured these platforms would offer api's that return embed code using a url as an input, but they do not. They do however offer  embed codes in the share functionality on their platforms. So i copied those embed codes, and just change the source in the iframe to the link that I want to display and it works. I usually have to add a '/embed' to the url or something, but alas, it works. It feels very hacky, but would this method be viable for a production application? I can share code if needed, but this is the premise of my question.